# Negative indexing is not supported in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to upload image and show the same in my site but instead i am getting this error

my current django-mptt version is 0.5.1

> views.py-

```
def home(request):
    print('here you go ')
    images=[]
    images=image_classification.objects.all()
    url=images[len(images)-1].pic.url
    return render(request,'home.html',{'print':'everything is ok','image':url})


#handles uploaded images
def uploadImage(request):
    print('image handling ')
    img= request.FILES['image']
    image=image_classification(pic=img)
    image.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

> inside models.py

```
from django.db import models


class image_classification(models.Model):
    pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

and the error i am facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prasa\Desktop\Pytorch-Django\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\prasa\Desktop\Pytorch-Django\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prasa\Desktop\Pytorch-Django\MainApp\ImageClassifier\views.py", line 10, in home
    url=images[len(images)-1].pic.url
  File "C:\Users\prasa\Desktop\Pytorch-Django\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 425, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError("Negative indexing is not supported.")

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: Negative indexing is not supported.
```

Comment: `images` is empty (the queryset), so `image_classification.objects.all()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what am i supposed to do here? follow up code is about uploading the image and showcasing it on page . what can i do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

images is empty (the queryset).you could handle if by using IF statment.

```
def home(request):
    print('here you go ')
    images=[]
    images=image_classification.objects.all()
    if len(imgaes) > 0:
  
  
   url=images[len(images)-1].pic.url
    else:
      url="place holder image url"
    return render(request,'home.html',{'print':'everything is ok','image':url})
```